# Mysqli recursive delete on same table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have comment system with table like this .
[Table Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQldr.jpg)

If a person delete the comment then all the row associated with that comment_parent also get deleted

i can write php recursive function which select the row and delete it .

The problem is if the comment has more than 100 of comment_parent, then more than 100 query will run to delete that.

Is it possible to delete comment along with its comment_parentid only with sql query , it will be great if anyone can help , i search and found CTE (but it doesn't support in mysqli i think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the `comment_parentid` column, deleting the parent item will automatically delete the child items (and their children, and their children, etc.).